# VSCode IntelliSense complete on full match

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, intellisense

Is there a way to complete intellisense suggestion on full match in VSCode?
When I typed a variable, method, keyword fully I want the suggestion to hide.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRLZw.png)

Cannot find an option to get the needed behavior.

Comment: Honestly, type space, closing bracket, semicolon, or anything and its gone anyway. If you really want it to disappear, just tab to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do is press `Esc` or `Tab` to close the *widget*.

Alternatively, you also have the command `hideSuggestWidget` that you can use to create a shortcut. Maybe use some type of `Ctrl+<>` to make that action quicker. Here you have the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) to create the shortcut.